# Sorting python dictionary by datatype

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have python dictionary combination of lists and string.

e.g

```python
dic = {"a": "11","c": [1,3,4], "b": [1,2,3], "g": "a"}
```

I want to sort it by datatype.

like

```python
dic = {"a": "11", "g": "a", "c": [1,3,4], "b": [1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have order! Use `collections.OrderedDict`, if you wish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dicts are inherently orderless, so you can only get a sorted list out of the dictionary. If you wish to get a list of key/value pairs, sorted by the type of the values, you can do it like this:

```
sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda pair: type(pair[1]), reverse=True)
```

This will give you the following list, with the string entries coming before the list entries:

```
[('a', '11'), ('g', 'a'), ('c', [1, 3, 4]), ('b', [1, 2, 3])]
```